# Why xargs -0 adds an extra blank line?

Tags: string, xargs, null

In the example, why `xargs -0` adds an extra blank line, and how to avoid it?

```
$ touch a b c
$ find . -print0
../a./c./b
$ find . -print0 | sort --zero-terminated | xargs -0
. ./a ./b ./c
$ find . -print0 | sort --zero-terminated 
../a./b./c$
```

Note that the last output is `../a./b./c$`  i.e. the `$` sign for input is on the same line without a new line.

Comment: I started an answer then you changed it completely.  Is that the output you mean?

Comment: @jsbillings Sorry for the change. I wanted to avoid new line from `xargs -0` as I am using mapfile to store the output as array. But, I was interested why xargs -0 was doing that behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `xargs -0 == xargs -0 echo` where the default echo will print new line at the end of a string,

You can achive the same output with `-n`

```
find . -print0 | sort --zero-terminated | xargs -0 -n1 echo -n
```